# Regex / Python3 - re.findall() - Find all occurrences between opcodes

Tags: regex, python-3.x, tlv

### Background

I'm reverse engineering a TCP stream that uses a Type-Length-Value approach to encoding data.

**Example:**

```
TCP Payload: b'0000001f001270622e416374696f6e4e6f74696679425243080310840718880e20901c'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type:     00 00   # New function call
Length:   00 1f   # Length of Value (Length of Function + Function + Data)
Value:    00 12   # Length of Function
Value:    70 62 2e 41 63 74 69 6f 6e 4e 6f 74 69 66 79 42 52 43   # Function ->(hex2ascii)-> pb.ActionNotifyBRC
Value:    08 03 10 84 07 18 88 0e 20 90 1c   # Data
```

However the Data is a data object that can include multiple variables with variable data lengths.

```
Data: 08 05 10 04 10 64 18 c8 01 20 ef 0f
----------------------------------------------
Opcode : Value
  08   :  05          # var1 : 1 byte
  10   :  04          # var2 : 1 byte
  18   :  c8 01       # var3 : 1-10 bytes
  20   :  ef 0f       # var4 : 1-10 bytes
```

Currently I am parsing the Data using the following Python3 code:

```
############################### NOTES ###############################
# Opcodes sometimes rotate starting positions but the general order is always held:
#     Data:     20 ef 0f 08 05 10 04 10 64 18 c8 01
#####################################################################

import re
import binascii

def dataVariable(data, start, end):
    p = re.compile(start + b'(.*?)' + end)
    return p.findall(data + data)

data = bytearray.fromhex('08051004106418c80120ef0f')
var3 = dataVariable(data, b'\x18', b'\x20')
print("Variable 3:", end=' ')
for item in set(var3):
    print(binascii.hexlify(item), end=' ')

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Output]: Variable 3: b'c801'
```

So far all good...

### Problem

If an Opcode appears in the previous variables Value the code is no longer reliable.

```
Data: 08 05 10 04 10 64 18 c8 20 01 20 ef 0f
----------------------------------------------
Opcode : Value
  08   :  05          
  10   :  04          
  18   :  c8 20 01        # The Value includes the next opcode (20)  
  20   :  ef 0f
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Output]: Variable 3: b'c8'
[Output]: Variable 4: b'0120ef0f'
```

I was expecting an output of:

```
[Output]: Variable 3: b'c8' b'c82001'
[Output]: Variable 4: b'0120ef0f' b'ef0f'
```

It seems like there is an issue with my regular expression?

### Update

To further clarify, var3 and var4 are representing integers.
I have managed to figure out how the length of the Value was being encoded. The most significant bit was being used as a flag to inform me that another byte was coming. You can then strip the MSB of each byte, swap the endianness and convert to decimal.

```
  data   ->   binary representation    -> strip MSB and swap endianness -> decimal representation

ac d7 05 -> 10101100 11010111 00000101 ->   0001 01101011 10101100      ->   93100
e4 a6 04 -> 11100100 10100110 00000100 ->   0001 00010011 01100100      ->   70500
90 e1 02 -> 10010000 11100001 00000010 ->        10110000 10010000      ->   45200
dc 24    ->          11011100 00100100 ->        00010010 01011100      ->   4700
f0 60    ->          11110000 01100000 ->        00110000 01110000      ->   12400
```

Comment: Can these values be overlapping? Like `18 56 18 20 57 20` with the result as `[b'56182057', b'5618', b'2057']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
def dataVariable(data, start, end):
    p = re.compile(b'(?=(' + start + b'.*' + end + b'))')
    res = []
    for x in p.findall(data):
        cur = b''
        for i, m in enumerate([x[i:i+1] for i in range(len(x))]):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            if m == end and cur:
                res.append(cur)
            cur = cur + m
    return res
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/QCIJF9610):

```
data = bytearray.fromhex('08051004106418c8200120ef0f0f') # => b'c82001' b'c8'
#data = bytearray.fromhex('185618205720') # => b'56182057' b'2057' b'5618' 
var3 = dataVariable(data, b'\x18', b'\x20')
print("Variable 3:", end=' ')
for item in set(var3):
    print(binascii.hexlify(item), end=' ')
```

Output is `Variable 3: b'c8' b'c82001'` for `'08051004106418c8200120ef0f0f'` string and `b'56182057' b'2057' b'5618'` for `185618205720` input.

The pattern is of `(?=(...))` type to find all overlapping matches. If you do not need the overlapping feature, remove these parts from the regex.

The point here is:

- match all substrings starting with `start` and up to the last `end` with `start + b'.*' + end` pattern
- iterate through the match dropping the first `start` byte and add an item to the resulting list when the `end` byte is found, adding up found bytes at each iteration (thus, getting all inner substrings inside the match).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank heaps! I need to read up more on regex, I havent had much experience. On my drive home today I figured I was disregarding something major. To further clarify, var3 and var4 are representing integers. I already knew how to parse this -> remove the most significant bit and swap the endianness, it works for two's complement as well. Anyway, that MSB I was discarding was actually a flag letting me know another byte was coming.  Thats how they were encoding the length.